# what's T[] object?

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

the constructor of ArrayAdapter is as follows:

`ArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)`

im new to java & android, i didn't see the data type `T[]` before, can anyone explain what it is or give me some web page about it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The T is either a concrete class type (unlikely), or it is a class generic. Look at your class heading to see if this is the case.

IE

```
Class SomeClassType<T> {}
```

Tutorials on generics and how they work can be found here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Comment: @Jeffrey Assumptions made about other people's code can lead to many wasted hours.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/gentypes.html

It is a generic type, which means that you can give any type you want to replace the T generic type.

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned, `T` in this case refers to a generic type. In other words, an `ArrayAdapter` can be used to handle objects of any type in order to bind the textual representation of those objects to Android `TextViews`.

A simple example would be to use an array of type `String`...

```
ArrayAdapter<String> myArrayAdapter;
String[] myArray = new String[] { "Hello", "World" } ;
myArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.id.my_textview, myArray);
```

Using `Strings` for `ArrayAdapter` is probably the most common approach although any object which implements `toString()` to return something meaningful can be used...

```
ArrayAdapter<SomeObject> myArrayAdapter;
SomeObject[] myArray = new SomeObject[] { ... } ;
myArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<SomeObject>(this, R.id.my_textview, myArray);
```

As long as `SomeObject.toString()` is implemented then the `TextView` represented by the resource id `R.id.my_textview` will be bound to its return value.

Answer (score 0):

T[] means generic type. Here is documentation on [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Comment: Not necessarily: some guy could have just decided to call his class `T`. It would not be good style, but it is legal.