# Clarification on how Stacks are implemented through Objects in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, object, stack, abstract

So I have a basic stack implementation here using an interface in Java and I had a couple of questions on how all this works,

```
public class ArrayStack<T> implements ArrayStackADT<T> {
private T[] ArrayStack;
private int top;

public ArrayStack() {
    ArrayStack = (T[]) new Object[20];
}
```

So I do understand that this line  `ArrayStack = (T[]) new Object[20];` creates an array implementation of a Stack with size 20 but I'm confused about what `(T[])` and '`new Object`' do and why they are required there? Could anyone describe it in Layman terms?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what's T\[\] object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237029/whats-t-object)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java

Comment: Because before the runtime compiler does not know what is the T,because we set it like ArrayStack<String>. Thus,when you want to create the array of generic types,you should make it with Object class which all classes extend this class.So,this will pass compilation because T extends Object no matter what T is.

Comment: As a side note, please follow some naming conventions: class names starting with an uppercase letter, method/variable starting with a lowercase letter. Especially if you want to name a class field the same way as the class itself.